# WPF DataGrid not showing data in columns with names that contain decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

XAML is super simple:

```
<TabItem Header="Year 1 Correlations" Name="tabItem_Correlations"
         Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle}">
   <Grid>
     <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="CorrelationsGrid"
               IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=ViewCorrelations}"/>
   </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

The data being passed in is a very simple DataTable.DefaultView with columns named after series being correlated.

When I look at the data behind the binding - both columns have data as expected.  But in the actual interface only the column without the number 0.25 shows data.

[image]

I can avoid this by doing:

```
series.Replace(".", "DOT")
```

on the column name before adding it to the DataTable:

[image]

et voila!  I guess a solution is to avoid decimal places, but could someone explain why?  Or am I just being dense...

Comment: Try putting the column names in []

Comment: Comic Sans, no, the horror!

Comment: It probably thinks of "." as of a property path separator at first.

Comment: @Blam putting the column names in square brackets breaks all bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` (Dot) is internally used by binding expression as property path separator.

Suppose you want to bind with some property B of class A, you would bind it using dot separator:

```
"{Binding Path=A.B}"
```

So, internally in your case **`Credit Spreads-GBP-0.25-AAA`**, binding engine is looking for property `25-AAA` in `Credit Spreads-GBP-0`.

If you look at output window of Visual Studio, you will see error logged over there for the same:

> Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value
>   exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Credit
>   Spreads-GBP-0.25-AAA; DataItem='NamedObject' (HashCode=18874777);
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text'
>   (type 'String')

---

Also, you can verify that by yourself. Hook `AutoGeneratingColumns` event and in handler check property path.

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,
                                     DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTextColumn textColumn = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
    var propertyPath = ((Binding)textColumn.Binding).Path.Path;
    // propertyPath will be Credit Spreads-GBP-0.25-AAA in your case.
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I assume there is no way to escape the decimal?  Given that the user is deciding which series to display I rather want to stick with autoGeneration.

Comment: Only other way is to let `AutoGenerateColumn` to be true and add manually another column under `Columns` collection of DataGrid.